# Can anyone help me understand this error? "definition of implicitly-declared ‘classA::classA()’"

Tags: c++

Heres the code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class classA
{                   
      protected:
                void setX(int a);

      private:
              int p;
};

classA:: classA()
{                      //error here.
 p = 0;
}

void classA:: setX(int a)
{
 p = a;    
}

int main()
{   
    system("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You forgot to declare the constructor in the class definition. Declare it in `public` section of the class (if you want clients to create instance using it):

```
class classA
{ 
      public: 
              classA();    // you forgot this!       
      protected:
                void setX(int a);

      private:
              int p;
};
```

Now you can write its definition outside the class which you've already done.

Comment: Actually, the thing which I know was that the default constructor is provided by the compiler by default. Here you have mentioned that definition of the constructor was missing. But, I was not knowing the 'WHY' we have to provide the default constructor when it is already being provided by the compiler. But, now, I knew that if we are defining the default constructor which is not in accordance with the one provided by the compiler, we will have to define it explicitly. I din't find the 'WHY'. :)

Comment: @Chaitanya: The compiler does generate a default constructor for you IF you don't declare (and define) one yourself. In the question, the OP has attempted to define the default constructor outside the class, without declaring it in the class. The code is ill-formed, and the compiler would generate error. Let me know if you understand it now **(see the code in the question to completely understand it)**.

Comment: I got the point now. So, its like once we define a default constructor, thats got to be declared. Otherwise one will be there by default. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 6):

```
class classA
{                   
      protected:
                classA(); // you were missing an explicit declaration!
                void setX(int a);

      private:
              int p;
};

classA:: classA()
{ 
 p = 0;
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your missing declaration should be `public` not `protected`

Comment: @Binary why do I miss `public`? An object of the class is not created anywhere outside of `classA` or one of its derived classes (of which there are none). Clearly the class is already designed to be derived from, because `setX` is protected.

Answer (score 1):

`classA` has no member named `classA()` to implement.

```
class classA
{
    // ....
    public:
       classA() ; // Missing the declaration of the default constructor.
};
```

Answer (score 0):

An empty constructor is provided by default: this is correct. But if you redefine it, it's not a default constructor any more. You have to declare and define it. If you only declare it (without the body), it's incorrect: you have to define it as well. If you define it without a declaration in the class, it's an error as well. You can though, "combine" declaration and definition by writing as follows:

```
class classA
{
    // ....
    public:
       classA() { p = 0;} 
};
```

or in this case even better:

```
class classA
{
    // ....
    public:
       classA():p(0) {} 
};
```