# c++ dynamic struct inside a class

Tags: c++, class, dynamic, struct

I'm still trying to learn C++ and my first approach came from a non object side of C. So I want to redo my structs and make use of the class data structure. I've come up with this.

In Gradebook.h

```
class Gradebook {
public:
//default constructor, initializes variables in private
Gradebook();
//accessor constructor, access members in private
private:
struct Student {
    int student_id;
    int count_student;
    string last;
    string first;
    };
struct Course {
    int course_id;
    int count_course;
    string name;
    Student *students;
    };
};
```

In my Gradebook.cpp

```
Gradebook::Gradebook() {

 Course *courses = new Course;
 courses->students = new Student;

 courses->count_course = 0;
 courses->course_id = 0;

 courses->students->count_student = 0;
 courses->students->student_id = 0;

}
```

**My Design**

I want to dynamically create `x_amount` to `Students` and `x_amount` of `Courses`.

**Problem**

I don't understand how to access my struct so I can start to add courses and students inside my struct.

I believe I can do the rest if I can try to access my struct and manipulate the members inside it. I've tried:

```
void Gradebook::newCourse(Course *courses) {

  //do stuff

}
```

When I try to compile it I get all kinds of errors:

```
In file included from gradebook.cpp:2:
./gradebook.h:9:18: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
        void newCourse(&Course);

gradebook.cpp:39:17: error: out-of-line definition of 'newCourse' does not match any
      declaration in 'Gradebook'
void Gradebook::newCourse(Course *courses) {


2 errors generated.
In file included from main.cpp:4:
./gradebook.h:9:18: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations
        void newCourse(&Course);
```

Any help for this noob is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are Student and Corse *inside* Gradebook class -- are they not seperate objects by themselves?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your whole design could use some work.

Your structs should initialize themselves. It also makes sense for them to be outside of `Gradebook`.

Here is a sample "C++ way" of doing this:

First note that [std::vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) is a dynamic array. Rather than needlessly managing your own memory, use `std::vector` instead. To use a `std::vector`, you need to put `#include <vector>` somewhere at the top of your file.

For `Student`, we removed the `count_student` variable. A container should keep track of the number of students. `Student` also initializes its own values now via a constructor. Notice how I am using a [constructor initialization list](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html).

```
struct Student 
{
    Student () ;

    int student_id;
    std::string first;
    std::string last;
};

Student::Student () : student_id (0)
{
}
```

We do similar things for `Course`. Once again, the important thing here is that `Course` is initializing and managing its own variables.

```
struct Course 
{
    Course () ;

    int course_id;
    std::string name;
    std::vector <Student> students;
};

Course::Course () : course_id (0)
{
}
```

The `Gradebook` class is now simplified. Notice how `NewCourse` takes a [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-pointer-variable-and-reference-variable-in-c) instead of a pointer.

```
class Gradebook {
public:
    Gradebook () ;

    void NewCourse (const Course &course) ;

private:
    std::vector <Course> courses;
};

Gradebook::Gradebook ()
{
}

void Gradebook::NewCourse (const Course &course)
{
    courses.push_back (course) ;
}
```

**Other thoughts**

I would probably take out the `std::vector <Student> students;` from `Course`. While yes, a course may have many students, a student may also take many courses. This many-to-many relationship may cause headaches or it may not.

One way of handling this is described in [this link](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148113/what-is-a-good-way-to-represent-a-many-to-many-relationship-between-two-classes). Another way would be to have to structure that stores pairs of students and courses.

**Update**

Here is the function signature for [std::vector::push_back](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/):

```
void push_back (const value_type& val);
```

As you can see, the function returns `void`, so you can't do something like `courses.push_back(id_number)->course_id`. This function only inserts an object into your vector.

Here is an example of how to use `std::vector` with the `Student` struct. First, just to make things a little easier, I'll add a new constructor to `Student`. Please note that I also changed `student_id` to just `id` to minimize redundancy.

```
struct Student 
{
    Student () ;
    Student (const int id, const std::string &first, const std::string &last) ;

    int id;
    std::string first;
    std::string last;
};

Student::Student () : id (0)
{
}

Student::Student (const int id, const std::string &first, const std::string &last)
    : id (id), first (first), last (last)
{
}
```

Here's an example of how to use a vector.

```
int main (void)
{
    // Create some students.
    Student s1 (1, "Bob", "Smith") ;
    Student s2 (2, "Katy", "Adams") ;
    Student s3 (3, "Mary", "Williams") ;

    // Create vector of students.
    std::vector <Student> students ;

    // Insert the students into the vector.
    students.push_back (s1) ;
    students.push_back (s2) ;
    students.push_back (s3) ;

    // Go through the students and print out data.
    for (unsigned n = 0; n < students.size (); ++n) {
        // Grab a reference to one of the students.
        Student &student = students [n] ; 

        // Print out information, be sure to #include <iostream> somewhere.
        std::cout << "ID: " << student.id
            << ", Name: " << student.first << " " << student.last << "\n" ;
    }

    // To update Bob's name to Rob.
    students [0].first = "Rob" ;

    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: @jiv902, I see, I was wondering how to use vector on a struct. I've tried using vector <Course> courses; then passing it to a function then it said it was unknown. So when I update a course id i would use courses.push_back(id_number)->course_id? I mean is this how its done? I understand this new concept your giving me but I also now have lots of questions on how courses.push_back updates course_id. Do you mind explaining it a bit more?

Comment: Also, I've tried your code and I got this following error. "error: definition of implicitly declared default constructor" in reference to Course::Course and Student:Student

Comment: @user2816227 You probably forgot to declare the constructor in the class definition itself. Also make sure you didn't skip any semi-colons or parenthesis. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5765780/can-anyone-help-me-understand-this-error-definition-of-implicitly-declared-cl) for more information. I also updated my answer a little. Hopefully it explains a bit more about what you want.

Comment: Thank you so much for that piece of code. While I have more questions that I have answers. Now I have a place to start learning. I'm reading over your links and googling all kinds of things. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The `Student` and `Course` are declared as private structs, so you cannot access them directly.

You have three options;

1. Make the seperate first class objects as their own classes.
2. Make the `Gradebook` have interfaces which can create and manipulate the `Students` and `Courses`.
3. Make the Students and Course public structs in the Gradebook

Comment: how can I manipulate Students and Courses if they are outside my Class?

Comment: The same way as you do it when they are inside.

Comment: Putting them inside the "private" section, does nothing to the object other than telling the compiler that only code belonging to Gradebook can access them.

Comment: isn't that good coding practice to put them inside the Gradebook class?

Comment: @Soren You should probably include in your answer the fact that he has no data members in his `Gradebook` class and his constructor is all wrong.

Comment: @jliv902 -- while that is a good point, I kind of assume that he had just cut back the code to what was minimal to ask his question...

Comment: @user2816227 -- It depends on what you are trying to do.   If Students  are never known outside Gradebook, then yes they should be private -- but intuitively Students and Courses can exist on their own -- you can have a student who have taken no course, and have no grades -- so I would suggest they are separate entities.

Comment: @jiv902, Again I am still new to C++, having learned C a few weeks ago. So I have a basic understanding on whats going on. But, everything I've googled hasn't come up with how to create class that is dynamic meaning the class grows as I add more information. In C I can create a struct using dynamic allocation and add information to it using. course[i].course_id...etc. I haven't found a way to do this in C++. So I reverted back to C methodology.

Comment: Eventually I want to be able to compare so I can send &course[i] into a function. Where i now will have its own information of student data etc... C seems to be easier, but I want to do it using C++ idioms.